# raspberry pi 4B wont booting

Tags: boot, boot-issues

[image]At that time when Windows was running smoothly, I tried to connect to the internet using an Android phone via USB tethering.  but suddenly my raspberry died, and didn't want to boot up again.  then I waited a few days because the RPI might overheat, and finally it started running again but suddenly it died again and until now it can't boot,I have booted eeprom until the screen is green, after that I replaced the SD card with Raspbian OS but the Raspberry doesn't boot

i use raspberry pi 4 b 8gb, power supply in = 100-240V~50/60Hz, out = 5.0V 3.0A.

i have boot eeprom from raspberry imager, and try to boot with raspbian os from raspberry imager

Comment: raspberry pi 4 b 8gb, power supply in = 100-240V~50/60Hz, out = 5.0V .0A

Comment: yes, i flash sd card with raspberry pi imager, 64 bit

Comment: sorry, that is 5.0 V 3.0 A

Comment: Edit your question with all these important details.

Comment: thank you, i have done it

Comment: Do you get the diagnostics screen when connected to hdmi screen and powered with no sd card?

Comment: yes, will put it in my question

Comment: It may be that Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm by default does not like your LCD screen. You could as a test try Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (Legacy).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try it later, when the problem occurs again I will update on this forum, once again Thank you

Comment: hi sir codermike, i have try with bullseye (legacy) 64 bit, and then the green leed blink 2 or 3 times, after a few times the led green is not blink anymore but my screen is still not booting or still black screen

Comment: Have you got a regular hdmi screen you can try?

Comment: Replace the SD card...

Comment: Have you got a regular hdmi screen you can try? – 
CoderMike

yes, and still not working

when i plug sdcard with windows os, raspi not booting, and led act light blinking 3 times